# Passing structs to functions and returning structs from functions in Zig

Tags: struct, zig

I am writing some Zig code that returns structs from functions and then passes these structs to other functions "by value" (i.e. I'm not explicitly passing a pointer) and it seems to be working, but I wonder if this is correct.

From [the docs](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Pass-by-value-Parameters) it looks like the compiler is implicitly deciding if the struct is going to be passed as an argument as a pointer or as a copy. Is this correct? So should I just pass  it "by value" whenever possible and leave it up to Zig to decide what to do?

What about returning a struct from a function? Is Zig always copying in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, prefer to pass structs as values, the compiler will optimize it, unless you need to [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021886/how-do-i-mutate-a-zig-function-argument) the original struct, in which case you'd have to pass a pointer to the struct.

I haven't seen anything in the documentation about the compiler optimizing returned struct values, but it likely does optimizations there. Even if not, prefer to return the struct as a value, since returning a pointer would [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75224846/944911) the usability of your functions.